# Elasticsearch - optimize aggregation without count?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I currently have an aggregation in elasticsearch that gets me the count for every subgroup, such as count of every color that meets a criteria (such as item was posted by certain user).

Gives me results such as:

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
       "countPerColor": {
          "buckets": {
             "yellow": {
                "doc_count": 501
             },
             "purple": {
                "doc_count": 999
             },
             "brown": {
                "doc_count": 0
             },
          }
       }
   }
}
```

This is more info than I need, since I don't need the counts, but only whether ANY exist (aka count > 0). Something like this would suffice:

```
{
   "yellow": true,
   "purple": true,
   "brown": false
}
```

Since I don't need counts, is there a way to improve my elasticsearch aggregation (either improving the aggregation or some function that doesn't require aggregations at all)?

Answer (score 0):

To filter data based on `doc_count` with aggregations, you can use [bucket_selector pipeline aggregation.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "color": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

```
{
  "color": "purple"
}
{
  "color": "purple"
}
{
  "color": "yellow"
}
{
  "color": "yellow"
}
{
  "color": "yellow"
}
{
  "color": "brown"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "the_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "the_doc_count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.the_doc_count > 1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "names": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "yellow",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "purple",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @user3861508 please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Hey! Apologies my question may not have been very clear, but currently I am already getting aggregation results by count. I think your answer was thinking I wanted to get rid of any aggregations that returned 0 results, but I actually want to return booleans for if count > 0 or not. A count would be fine too, but I'm thinking that if I only need a boolean (or if it stops counting after finding any result for that bucket) then I can improve performance by stopping unnecessary further processing?